# Обработка нажатия клавиши C#

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Как обработать событие по нажатию клавиши (например, в текстбоксе), чтобы при попытке ввода символа "|" ничего не происходило?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фильтруйте ввод в OnKeyPress:

```
public class FilteredTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '|')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

Имейте в виду, что ввести запрещенный символ можно не только напрямую, набирая его на клавиатуре, но и вставив из буфера обмена. Думаю, целесообразно было бы использовать ту же логику, что и в стандартном NumericUpDown (посмотрите исходники).

Comment: да это-то понятно и так, вопрос в другом. Как присвоить новое значение клавише? я проверяю в событии OnKeyPress: if (e.keyChar==220) e.KeyChar=(char)0;

Но это не работает. Как задать пустую клавишу?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Очень хороший и простой способ. Использование свойства "Handled" дает практически совершенный результат. Вот только, правда, остается еще копирование из буфера обмена.

Comment: Думаю, что у меня приемлемо было бы и просто, по выполнению каких-либо действий с введенными данными, использовать метод Replace и заменять пустым символом.

Answer (score 1):

Или проверяйте наличие запрещенных символов в `OnTextChanged`.